# After deleting extension keyboard app still showing (null) - MyKeyboard on iOS keyboard globe button

Tags: ios, keyboard, swift3

Recently I have noticed that, After deleting my custom keyboard app from iPhone still showing as "Null" in iOS keyboard globe button.

Anyone please answer if they also faced this issue.

Refer screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has happened to me before and still does. It could be an iOS 10 bug(please correct me if I'm wrong). With that said, I fixed the issue by simply going to: **Settings - General - Keyboards - Edit** and then manually **delete** the respected keyboard.

Comment: Yes I have also noticed that, this is iOS 10 bug.